# Rigorously validate a GeoJSON polygon

Tags: polygon, geojson, topology

I have a GeoJSON polygon which I'm suspicious about. It doesn't render properly in several different tools.

[Mapbox's Geojson-hint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mapbox/geojsonhint) gives it a clean bill of health.

The shape has many internal holes, and I suspect some of these may be duplicate or have other weirdness.

Are there any more rigorous ways of checking a polygon?

Comment: Can you share it?

Comment: Not readily, and I'm more interested in learning general solutions than solving this particular one.

Comment: Having a sample and try different methods might lead to general solution.

Comment: "It doesn't render properly in several different tools": which ones? e.g for example, D3 use the opposite rules to draw correctly e.g https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49311001/d3-js-drawing-geojson-incorrectly. Depending the issue may lie in the tools renderer or the GeoJSON or both... Geospatial is always so easy :)

Comment: Is it in CRS:84 as required by the specification?

Answer (score 0):

The beginning of an answer:

- Winding issues depending of tools used that use right or left order to render. HTML Canvas based tools are sensitive to this e.g [TMCW article on GeoJSON in particular the winding part](https://macwright.com/2015/03/23/geojson-second-bite.html#winding) and [this D3 related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49311001/d3-js-drawing-geojson-incorrectly)
- You can use QGIS from CLI to validate your input (possible in the GUI but a pain for automation) e.g

```bash
qgis_process run qgis:checkvalidity -- INPUT_LAYER=your_input_file.geojson METHOD=1 IGNORE_RING_SELF_INTERSECTION=0 VALID_OUTPUT=/tmp/valid.shp INVALID_OUTPUT=/tmp/invalid.shp ERROR_OUTPUT=/tmp/error.shp
```

If you wonder where the args come from, type `qgis_process help qgis:checkvalidity` and see also QGIS doc section ["Using processing from the command line"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing/standalone.html). Below the interesting output excerpt of the `qgis_process help qgis:checkvalidity`

```
...
METHOD: Method
    Argument type:  enum
    Available values:
        - 0: The one selected in digitizing settings
        - 1: QGIS
        - 2: GEOS
    Acceptable values:
        - Number of selected option, e.g. '1'
        - Comma separated list of options, e.g. '1,3'
IGNORE_RING_SELF_INTERSECTION: Ignore ring self intersections
    Argument type:  boolean
    Acceptable values:
        - 1 for true/yes
        - 0 for false/no
...
```

Geos or QGIS algorithm METHOD and IGNORE_RING_SELF_INTERSECTION may change the result concerning validity.

- You can also use GDAL approach (it uses Geos library behind the scene) with

```
ogr2ogr -f CSV /vsistdout/ -dialect SQLite States/Admin2.shp -sql 'SELECT *, GEOS_GetLastWarningMsg(), ST_AsText(GEOS_GetCriticalPointFromMsg()) FROM "Admin2" WHERE NOT ST_IsValid(geometry)'
```

Above sample can be tested with data from https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/handling_invalid_geometries.html To understand where the `GEOS_GetCriticalPointFromMsg` or `GEOS_GetLastWarningMsg` come from, look at [Spatialite Proj/Geos error doc](https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-5.0.1.html#error)